# Hidden cells in html table causing larger row height

Tags: html, css

So I have an HTML Table that is acting as a summary table for a list of things I need to display. I have only 4 columns showing but there are approx. 20 and they're currently set to `display: none;`. The problem is those hidden cells are causing rows to be larger than the visible ones need. (I Would just delete the hidden ones but later functionality dictates that user's will need to be able to make those cells/columns visible)

**Question**: Is there a way to make the row's height as tall as the visible ones need (and nothing more) and adjust as cells/columns visibility change?

**Current CSS:**

```
table.grid {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.grid tr td {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}

table.grid tr td input {
    display: block;   
}
```

With this I've successfully eliminated the horizontal white-space between cells but I need to eliminate the vertical space now and I'm not sure how to overcome this little hiccup.

Comment: Could you recreate your problem in http://jsfiddle.net/ please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your hidden cells.

```
.class{
  display:none;
  line-height:0;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Not sure why that's needed though as I thought the whole point of `display:none;` over the `visible` route was that formatting didn't apply. Anyways thanks.

Comment: display:none has worked correctly for me 99% of the time.. When dealing with cells sometimes it gets hung... What browser were u testing in ?

Comment: I'm testing in chrome currently, plan on testing in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Opera for production.

Comment: chrome typically works fine... check out jdbechtold.com.. the hidden divs are set to display none and dont take up any space